# Vigenere Cipher Incredibly Confused

Tags: python, encryption, vigenere

ive been stuck on this for hours now. I've been trying to encrypt a preset message with a preset vigenere key. so that the name lets say 'bob' shifts by the key 'abc' it shifts the word bob by the ascii values 'abc'.

I have this code right now but it isn't printing anything whatsoever and i'm incredibly confused on how to do this.

```
def vigenere(key, letter):

    keyVal = ord(key)
    letterVal = ord(letter)

    keyVal = keyVal - 97

    letterVal = keyVal + letterVal

    if letterVal >= ord("z"):
        letterVal = letterVal - 26

        print letterVal
```

Comment: How are you calling this function? Or is the problem that you aren't?

Comment: @tripleee i thought i was calling it by assigning them to the letterval / keyval variables.

Comment: You're not calling `vignere(key, letter)` anywhere in your example... do you just need to call it with `key` and `letter` params?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do that in loop for a string, like I did below:

```
def vigenere(key, letter):

    letterChar = ""
    for i in range(len(letter)):
        keyVal = ord(key)
        letterVal = ord(letter[i])
        keyVal = keyVal - 97
        letterChar += chr(keyVal + letterVal)
        if letterVal >= ord('z'):
            letterVal = letterVal - 26

    print letterChar


vigenere('c', "pop")
```

It returns:

```
rqr
```

Comment: how would i print a phrase out with a key? Like ascii key to shift the individual characters within the phrase for example if the phrase was cat and the key was abc. The c would become d, the a would become c and the t would become w. Making cat into dcw.

Comment: you mean decryption?

Comment: not decryption im a complete noob when it comes to python all it does is create a encrypted phrase with an ascii shift on the individual letters thank you for the help so far

Comment: @SepZ check the edited answer, Now it is showed that "pop" becomes "rqr" with key: "c". Here c = 2, because you are subtracting 97 (i.e 'a') from c

Comment: I didn't use 'a' here, it wont make any effect, because 'a'-'a' is 0, so the 'pop' will remain same as 'pop'

Comment: Accept the answer if it helps you